# How to order $x = \sqrt{3}-1, y = \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}, z = 1+\sqrt{2}$ ascendingly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

How would I order $x = \sqrt{3}-1, y = \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}, z = 1+\sqrt{2} \ $ without approximating the irrational numbers? In fact, I would be interested in knowing a general way to solve such questions if there is one.

What I tried to so far, because they are all positive numbers, is to square $x,y,z$ but, obviously, the rational parts will not be equal so I cannot compare the radicals. Proving that $x<z$ is easy and so is $y<z$, but I'm stuck at $x < y \text{ or } x>y$.

Comment: $\sqrt{3}-1<1+\sqrt{2}$ is clear, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, I added that as well as $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}<1+\sqrt{2}$ just now, as I initially forgot to mention it.

Comment: You are comparing $\sqrt{3} - 1$ and $\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{2}$. Equivalently, you are comparing $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5} + 1$. Since they are both positive, you can compare the squares $5 + 2 \sqrt{6}$ and $6 + 2 \sqrt{5}$, or equivalently $2 \sqrt{6}$ and $2 \sqrt{5} + 1$. Now square one last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is as follows. It can be proved that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function. So we have:
$$x_1\lt x_2 \implies \sqrt{x_1}\lt \sqrt{x_2} \implies \sqrt{x_2} - \sqrt{x_1} \gt 0$$This implies that $x,y\gt 0$. Also $g(x) = x^2$ is an increasing function for $x\ge 0$, then:
$$x_1\lt x_2 \implies x_1^2\lt x_2^2 \ \ \ \ x_1,x_2\in [0,\infty)$$
Now suppose $x\gt y$:
$$x>y \implies x^2\gt y^2 \implies (\sqrt{3} -1)^2>(\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{2})^2 \implies 3+1-2\sqrt{3}\gt 5+2-2\sqrt{10} \implies -3-2(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{10})\gt 0 \implies -3\gt 2(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{10}) \implies 3<2(\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{3})\implies \frac{3}{2}\lt \sqrt{10}-\sqrt{3} \implies \frac{9}{4} \lt 10 +3-2\sqrt{30} \implies 2\sqrt{30}\lt 13 - \frac{9}{4} \implies 4\times30\lt \frac{43^2}{4^2} \implies 4^3\times30 \lt 43^2 \implies 1920\lt 1849$$
This is a contradiction and implies $x\lt y$. Other cases can be checked similarly.

Comment: This solution is really similar to other things I've learnt in class, so I really should've thought of this! Thanks a lot for such a general solution!

Comment: @J__n You're welcome. Always be careful about applying a function to the both sides of an inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $0 < x, y < 1$ and simple calculation shows $y = \sqrt{7-2\sqrt{10}}$ so the claim reduces to showing $y^2 - x^2 = 3 - 2\sqrt{10} + 2\sqrt{3} > 0$, i.e. that $\sqrt{10} < \sqrt{3} + \frac 32$. To show this, square both sides to see this is equivalent to $10 < \frac{21}{4} + 3 \sqrt{3}$, i.e. that $19 < 12 \sqrt{3}$. Squaring one final time, this is equivalent to $361 < 432$ which is obvious so we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ x \geqslant y $, then

$$ \begin{array} { r c l }
\sqrt3 + \sqrt2 &\geqslant& \sqrt5 + 1 \\
(\sqrt3 + \sqrt2)^2 &\geqslant& (\sqrt5 + 1)^2 \\
5 + 2 \sqrt6 &\geqslant& 6 + 2 \sqrt5 \\
2( \sqrt6 - \sqrt5) &\geqslant& 1 \\
2( \sqrt6 - \sqrt5)( \sqrt6 + \sqrt5) &\geqslant& ( \sqrt6 + \sqrt5) \\
2(6 - 5) &\geqslant&  \sqrt6 + \sqrt5 \\
2 &\geqslant&  \sqrt6 + \sqrt5 > \sqrt4 + \sqrt4 = 4 \\
\end{array} 
$$

A contradiction.

Comment: You could also proceed from your $$  ( \sqrt6 - \sqrt5)  \ \geqslant \ \frac12 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \sqrt6    \ \geqslant \ \frac12 \ + \sqrt5 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ 6 \  \ \geqslant \ \frac14 \ + \sqrt5 \ + \ 5  \ \geqslant \ \frac14 \ + 1 \ + \ 5 \ \ , $$ again a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

A visual demonstration of sorts:

Starting from $ \ x \ = \ \sqrt3 - 1 \ \ , \ $ we have
$$ x \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ \sqrt3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ + \ 2x \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 3 \ \ . \ $$   So $ \ \sqrt3 - 1 \ $ is the larger of the two zeroes of $ \ x^2 + 2x - 2 \ \ . \ $  As for $ \ x \ = \ \sqrt5 \ - \ \sqrt2 \ \ , \ $ we may write
$$ x \ + \ \sqrt2 \ \ = \ \ \sqrt5 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ + \ 2 \sqrt2 · x  \ + \ 2 \ \ = \ \ 5  \ \ , $$
making $ \ \sqrt5 \ - \ \sqrt2 \ $ the larger of the two zeroes of the polynomial $ \ x^2   +   2 \sqrt2 · x    -   3 \ \ . \ $   A graph of the two polynomials (the first in red, the second in blue) indicates the relative positions of these two zeroes.

If one mistrusts a graph (a not unreasonable attitude), we can show that the curve for $ \ x^2 + 2x - 2 \ $ lies "above" that of $ \ x^2   +   2 \sqrt2 · x    -   3 \ \ $ [vertex at $ \ (-1 \ , \ -3) \ $ *versus* $ \ (-\sqrt2 \ , \ -5)  \ \ , \ $ "higher" $ \ y-$ intercept; also, $$   x^2 + 2x - 2 \ > \ x^2 + 2 \sqrt2 x - 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 1 \ > \ 2·(\sqrt2 - 1)·x $$ $$  \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{2·(\sqrt2 - 1)} \ = \ \frac12·(1 + \sqrt2) \ > \ x \ \ . \ ] $$ until the curves intersect at $ \ x \ = \ \frac{1}{2 \sqrt2 \ - \ 1} \ = \ \frac12   +  \frac{\sqrt2}{2} \ \ , $ $  y \ = \ \frac32 \sqrt2 - \frac14 \ > \ 0 \ \ . \ $  Since this intersection is "above" the $ \ x-$axis, the positive $ \ x-$intercept of $ \ x^2 + 2x - 2 \ $ is smaller than that of $ \ x^2   +   2 \sqrt2 · x    -   3 \ \ . $

[image]